# Strange 404 Errors

Tags: 404

A client is suddenly getting 404 Errors on new entries. Old entries display correctly. New entries display correctly when the site is put into Dev Mode. The pages preview correctly if any content is updated, but not at first. Error log below.

Ive reset the slug. Ive reset the post date (which is the second part if the url). Nada...

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

`2021-04-08 09:10:50 [-][-][l828l4pver7098opi4rbsfparg][error][yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Template not found: films/2021/fauna in /var/www/vhosts/thecinematheque.ca/domains/thecinematheque.ca/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php:92`

Answer (score 1):

Clearing Crafts's caches fixed this issue. Very strange!